# identified(by: \.self) - what does it do?

Tags: swift, swiftui, keypaths

In this video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/103/, the following snippet of code is shown at around 15:30:

```
...
ForEach(ContentSizeCategory.common.identified(by: \.self))
...
```

What does it do? Where does `self` points to? The current object (`TraitCell_Preview`)? It doesn't even compile in my computer since `common` isn't a member in `ContentSizeCategory`. I thought I had seen it before in a `SwiftUI` talk (`\.self`) . `Keypath`'s aren't my best thing in Swift though.

I understand `ForEach`'s elements needs to be `Identifiable`. `self` (a.k.a. `TraitCell_Preview` right?) does only conform to `PreviewProvider` so not `Identifiable` (if the private `_PreviewProvider` protocol from which `PreviewProvider` conforms to doesn't conform to `Identifiable`, not sure about that since I can not see the code).

What is `\.self` in the snippet of code and where does it points to?

Comment: Nonsense that this question is marked as a duplicate question when the other question is asked later than this question. The other linked question should be marked as the duplicated question.

Comment: If there was no upvoted or accepted answer at the moment Sulthan maked your question as dupe, they couldn't have done so. More info [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187827/should-questions-be-marked-as-duplicate-if-the-older-question-has-no-accepted-an)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Looks like `common` is a `static` variable that they created to help their demo. It's just an extension on `ContentSizeCategory`. Something like this:

```
extension ContentSizeCategory {
     static var common = [ContentSizeCategory.accessibilityLarge,
                          ContentSizeCategory.accessibilityMedium,
                        ContentSizeCategory.extraSmall]

}
```

2. `ContentSizeCategory` is an enum, conforms to Hashable that means every type is uniquely identifiable. Below is the signature of `identified` function, when it is called you need to tell what's the key path that it should use in order to uniquely identify items. So `\.self` is basically telling the whole self is unique because it conforms to Hashable.

```
func identified<ID>(by getID: KeyPath<Binding<Value.Element>, ID>) -> IdentifierValuePairs<Binding<Value>, ID> where ID : Hashable
```

Answer (score 1):

Method `self` is a property that returns the object itself, for example:

```
let string = "text"
print(string[keyPath: \.self]) // "text"
```

We also use it when accessing types, e.g. `Int.self`.

I assume that the entire instance is used as identifier.

Comment: So that means the member common is Identifiable? It's a shame it doesn't compile so I can not have a look myself

Comment: @J.Doe It's an enumeration. That means the values are already unique and you don't have to provide any other unique identifier. However, since we cannot really compile, I wouldn't worry about that now.